# Geometry shader in web

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, opengl-es-3.1

I'm interested to use geometry shader in web(site / application)
Is it possible to directly use opengl es 3.1 in web without webgl?
Is any other API to use newer version of opengl es than webgl2?

Totally is any way to I can use geometry shader in web?

thanks in advance

**EDIT :** 
or is anyway to use opengl in web?

Comment: No: WebGL2 just shipped this year. (In fact it hasn't shipped in Edge or Safari yet). It will likely be several years before there are any new versions with newer features like geometry shaders.

Comment: Yeah I know that webgl2 is releasing recently. but I'm trying to find something else to go throw this limitation of webgl. 
I think that this feature can not be added to webgl2 by extensions , am I true?

Comment: WbGL doesn't have any official support for geometry shaders, and won't at any time in the near future. It is possible to use textures to emulate a many to one relationship in the vertex shader. https://acko.net/blog/yak-shading/

Answer (score 2):

> Is any other API to use newer version of opengl es than webgl2

No

> Is it possible to directly use opengl es 3.1 in web without webgl

No

> is any way to I can use geometry shader in web?

No

> is anyway to use opengl in web?

No (wrt using anything else besides OpenGL ES 3.0 using WebGL 2.0)

> I think that this feature can not be added to webgl2 by extensions

Well in theory it could, in fact the majority of API features were extensions once. As of now though there's no extension exposing geometry shaders for WebGL 2